# Rent Access to Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Thanks in advance for a question from a newbie.

I have a custom Chrome extension that members of my site would pay to use. Is there a way for them to "rent" access for a certain period of time?  I do not want to uninstall the extension remotely.  I only want to prevent it from working for the times where they haven't paid.  This will have relatively few users, so I can manually determine who gets access, but I want to know if there is a way to issue a key/token remotely for the extension to do its thing.

Thanks,
Steve

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try [In-App Payments](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap). You can set monthly or yearly billing period.